# how to make evernote like tableview header?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

When I add UISearchBar to UITableView, I can't put the other ui controls to header. 
How to make UITableView Header like Evernote?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats a separate view that been added as header to the table view. Plus there are controls with slight modification too. First two are segment controls. 3rd you can create as custom UIButton with that background image for UIControlStateNormal. Then add the searchbar. implementation of that will totally depend on your requirements. Linking up IBAction methods in IB is one of the ways.